# Properly highlighting macros for C in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to highlight certain function-like macros for C in Vim, and I'm having trouble with what type of highlighting category I should give it. The goal of this is to add highlighting support for some C libraries.

At a first glance, looking at [`c.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/c.vim) the most suitable keyword groups seems to be `cConstant`, `cPreProc`, `cDefine` and `cOperator`. Here `cPreProc` and `cDefine` are made to go along with `#`, which leaves me to `cOperator` and `cConstant`. I'm not very proficient in computer science, but macros does not seem to (in general) fit very well into operators, and so this leaves me to `cConstant`. I could interpret this as a constant expression modulo inputs, which then makes sense.

Is `cConstant` the best fit for this, should I define a new highlighting group, or should I not highlight them at all?

Comment: A sample would be great.

Comment: `#define MY_MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing `:help group` says that the group `Macro` is the same as `Define`, which is what `cDefine` is linked as. Thus, one should use `cDefine` or perhaps define a new group called `cMacro` which is linked to `Macro`. Don't really know why Bram made it like this.